# Second Sub-SELECT statement not returning value with UNION

Tags: sql, union, sql-server-2019

Why does this query...

```
SELECT DISTINCT [COS_JobTitle] AS 'Name'
FROM (
    SELECT [COS_BpsID] AS [COS_BpsID], [COS_JobTitle] AS [COS_JobTitle]
    FROM [CacheOrganizationStructure]
    WHERE [COS_AccountType] = 1

    UNION
        
    SELECT WFD_AttChoose3 AS WFD_AttChoose3, NULL
    FROM WFElements
    WHERE WFD_ID = 53584
) AS nnn

ORDER BY 'Name'
```

...not return the value from the second sub-SELECT statement?

```
SELECT WFD_AttChoose3 AS WFD_AttChoose3, NULL
    FROM WFElements
    WHERE WFD_ID = 53584
```

Once I amend the entire query to omit the second column for each sub-SELECT statement query it works as expected, i.e. `, [COS_JobTitle] AS [COS_JobTitle]` And `, NULL`

Comment: FYI `ORDER BY 'Name'` likely isn't doing what you think it is. That would order your dataset by the *literal string* `'Name'`, which means your data is *unordered*. As such the `ORDER BY` might as well be omitted, as it doesn't achieve anything.

Comment: Try run your subquery in isolation. The UNION requires that both queries being UNIONed have the same number of columns with the same datatypes

Comment: Also T-SQL is a SQL dialect that is used by multiple products including Sybase, SQL Server, and Azure Synapse. What is the (R)DBMS product you are using here? [Edit] your question to tag that product, and (if relevant) the version tag for the product as well.

Comment: You say that if you remove `COS_JobTitle` from the subquery it works as you expect, but that *can't* be true; the outer query is simply `DISTINCT COS_JobTitle` so if you remove `COS_JobTitle` from the derived table you'll get an error.

Comment: Well, you're right, I meant removing one column. From the first subquery I have to remove [COS_BpsID] AS [COS_BpsID] and from the second one NULL. I know the union'ed queries have to have the same number of columns. Executing the second subquery on its own does indeed return the value I'm missing. Just the posted query does not with two or more columns in the subquery.

Comment: yor query works as intended https://dbfiddle.uk/X7Aaveh7  maybe you can add a sample that doesn't work

Comment: Sample data (preferably as a full script with `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT`) as well as expected results, would help immensely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out everything worked with a different set of tables. Did not follow through investigating that, though.